# Java RMI's UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, rmi

I am currently practicing the implementation of RMI in Java. One of the requirements is to create a class that extends the UnicastRemoteObject which contains functions that can be called remotely.

I'd like to know if the class that extends the UnicastRemoteObject is shared by all connected clients. What I mean by sharing is that, is the instance object created from the class that extends the UnicastRemoteObject is concurrently used by connected clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you use it. Normally if that's the only remote object, you would register a single instance of it in the RMI Registry, then the clients look it up and call methods on it, and they are all sharing the same instance. However if you look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912558/207421) you will see how to allocate one per client, if that's your requirement.

Comment: Interesting, yes I remember binding the name for the object in the registry. So if I am not mistaken, one registry is to one instance of the remote object. So basically if there are 2 clients that connects on the same registry, then that means they are sharing the same remote object. Is my analogy right?

Comment: As I've just answered, 'they are all sharing the same instance'.

Comment: Yes you did, was just confirming if I understand you right. A follow up question, if 2 clients connect on the same registry and they share the same object, are they using the object at the same time (concurrently)? Or are they controlled by some mechanism that won't allow a function (or the object) to  be used at the same time?

Comment: There are no guarantees about threading in the RMI Specification. What that means is that you cannot assume it is single threaded. Any synchronization required is your responsibility.